# How can i reduce size of letters

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to reduce size of letters, The thing is that the letters a very big
(look at the 1st screenshot), i would like to that the text was smaller. How can i to do it?

[1st screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjttC.png)

Comment: Please add the layout xml file to see the parameters of the TextViews

Comment: Use `textSize`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have used textSize in your view then reduce the value of it,

***if not***

add this to your view

```
android:textSize="12sp"//change the 12sp according to your requirements

//increase the value of 12sp if you want the text to be larger/bigger
//decrease the value of 12sp if you want the text to be smaller/reduce the size of text
```

Comment: you don't use dp with text size, you use sp

Comment: @a_local_nobody ok !